# Length of arc - problem with the integration.

Tags: integration

I have a question about calculating the length of arc.

I know the formula but I can't see the trick I am missing in the integration.  The question in my text book is:

Find the length of the curve $4xy = x^2 + 4$ between x = 1 and x = e.

[image: Curve in Desmos]

The solution in the back of the book is $\frac{e^2+7}{8}.$

I know the standard formula for the length of the arc (S).

$$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + \Big( \frac{dy}{dx}} \Big)^2   dx$$

I get $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2-4}{4x^2}$ and if I square top and bottom, and add 1, 1 + $\Big( \frac{dy}{dx} \Big)^2 = \frac{17x^4-8x^2+16}{16x^4}$

This leaves me with an integral that I don't know how to simplify because of the square root:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{e} \sqrt{\frac{17x^4-8x^2+16}{x^4}}  dx$$

Have I made a mistake in getting to this stage, or is there something I can do now?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your work...and that integral is a horrendous being. You could try some kind of hyperbolic substitution...and even then it'll be extraordinarily hard to solve

Comment: It looks to me like you have lost a sign- that first term should be 15x^4, not 17x^4.

Comment: I think it's OK as 17x^4.  Even is if it's 15x^4 I still don't know where to go with it. I was just doing it to test my understanding so as long as I am not missing something obvious I'll just move on to the next question.  Thanks to both of you for looking at it.